# "incremental equations" in xaringan?

Tags: r, r-markdown, xaringan

I would like to know if there is any way to do "incremental equations" in xaringan, analogous to doing incremental slides with `--`?

I'm thinking of something like this (which, obviously, wouldn't work):

```
\begin{align}
x &= 1/2 \\
--
  &= 0.5 
\end{align}
```

Comment: It's not impossible but not straightforward, either. One idea is to write the equation in an R character vector, and output each line (with the last line `\end{align}`) incrementally via `cat()` and `results='asis'`. I don't have time to elaborate, and hope someone else could help you if you can't figure it out. Another (simpler) idea is to use template slides: https://slides.yihui.org/xaringan/incremental.html For either idea, I'm not sure if it's worth the effort.